# div overflow in nokia 5800 browser

Tags: html, overflow, nokia

I have an outer div, inner div and a table inside the inner div. outer div has overflow style property set to hidden and its width is made 100%. inner div's overflow property is set to auto.table has a width of 300%.

Browser in nokia 5800 is giving me horizontal scroll bar at the bottom whereas the page fits correctly in nokia 603 browser.

What might be the reason for overflow from screen even if outer div has above mentioned styles set?

Same arrangement with a div instead of table fits correclty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Widths are generally inherited from parent controls.
What is the parent of `outer div` ?
Second point to note is that, the inner most `table` has a width of 300% ? which will obviously overflow.
Can you post your `HTML` ?

Comment: Ya. You are right.body has given width of 105% in css file linked for nokia 5800. my outer div is directly under body.Thank you.